# Positioning nested Divs with only horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

I need to have only horizontal scrolling in my example provided [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3c7AE/) .
 Now I know there have been posts with similar problems here where the answer was as simple as having `{overflow-x:auto; and overflow-y:hidden;}` in the CSS. I tried that, and for some reason, I am not getting the result that I am looking for. What I want is to have only horizontal scrolling. I need this so that when more features and links are added in the HTML file, it does not drop down like it is doing in my jsfiddle. My entire code looks like this:

**CSS:**

```
body {
  font-family: "marcellus sc";
}

body p{
  font-family: "trebuchet ms";
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.links_wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(246,217,90,0.7);
  border:3px solid #c5a101;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 398px;
  width:95%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}

.links_title {
  height: 40px;
  width:98%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 358px;
  width:98%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.ind_blocks {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 348px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(248,217,10,0.4);
  padding: 5px;
}

.ind_blocks div {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width:20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(90,90,90,0.7);
  border: 2px solid #c5a101;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.ind_blocks div:hover {
  background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.5);
  color: #ffd000;
}

.ind_blocks div #under_constr {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display:none;
  top:100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

.ind_blocks div:hover > #under_constr {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

div .img_n_text {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(99,199,249,0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

div .img_n_text img {
  width: 97%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div .img_n_text h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

div .img_n_text p {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="links_wrapper">
  <div class="links_title">Head Menu:</div>
  <div class="scroll">

    <div class="ind_blocks">
      <a style="text-decoration:none; " href=""  >
        <div>
          <div id="under_constr">
            <p>Under Construction</p>
          </div>
          <div class="img_n_text">
            <img src="img/blubox149x121.jpg" />
            <h4>Head1</h4>
            <p>Aut fabulas do probant.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a style="text-decoration:none; " href=""  >
        <div>
          <div id="under_constr">
            <p>Under Construction</p>
          </div>
          <div class="img_n_text">
            <img src="img/blubox149x121.jpg" />
            <h4>head2</h4>
            <p>Id esse consequat arbitror.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a style="text-decoration:none; " href=""  >
        <div>
          <div id="under_constr">
            <p>Under Construction</p>
          </div>
          <div class="img_n_text">
            <img src="img/blubox149x121.jpg.jpg" />
            <h4>head3</h4>
            <p>Se tamen cohaerescant.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a style="text-decoration:none; " href=""  >
        <div>
          <div id="under_constr">
            <p>Under Construction</p>
          </div>
          <div class="img_n_text">
            <img src="img/blubox149x121.jpg.jpg" />
            <h4>head4</h4>
            <p>Anim voluptate de labore fore.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a style="text-decoration:none; " href=""  >
        <div>
          <!--<div id="under_constr">
            <p>Under Construction</p>
          </div>-->
          <div class="img_n_text">
            <img src="img/blubox149x121.jpg.jpg" />
            <h4>Links</h4>
            <p>Hic offendit ex admodum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a style="text-decoration:none; " href=""  >
        <div>
          <div id="under_constr">
            <p>Under Construction</p>
          </div>
          <div class="img_n_text">
            <img src="img/blubox149x121.jpg.jpg" />
            <h4>Sixth Link</h4>
            <p>If more features gets added...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to resolve this primarily with CSS and use JavaScript only as a last resort.
What am I doing wrong? Or what am I missing?

 
Update: I am attaching a screenshot of the result i am getting after i applied RCNeil's answer, [Here](http://img42.com/iIErv). It still was not doing what I wanted. I am currently in the process of going thru other answers to see which one fits my need. I will update soon. I am sorry for my code being messy and inefficient. I am still learning the ins and outs and what better way to learn than just doing it, right?Thanks for the help again.

Comment: did you mean on hover the transparent black div gets out of the box, and that's your problem?

Comment: display:flex, table or inline-block + white on child will do . example with flex : http://jsfiddle.net/3c7AE/2/ you should first style the horizontal scrolling result, and then applied your 'design/colors' style to the whole thing. your code is a bit messy and unefficient :) , good luck  http://jsfiddle.net/3c7AE/5/

Comment: so the 3 option i think of : **flex""   http://jsfiddle.net/3c7AE/5/  **table** http://jsfiddle.net/3c7AE/6/ **inline-block** http://jsfiddle.net/3c7AE/7/

Comment: @GCyrillus- You've given a series of choices! so fast!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "simplest case" example of the effect you're trying to accomplish. Note here there is only one div, with children that are laid out horizontally and scroll on the x axis.

The main trick is white-space:nowrap; on the div that you want to scroll, and to make sure you reset white-space:normal; on it's children, so that text wraps as you'd expect.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n67Gk/

HTML:

```
<div class="scroll">
    <a href="#">
        This scrolls
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        This scrolls
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        This scrolls
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        This scrolls
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        This scrolls
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        This scrolls
    </a>   
        <a href="#">
        This scrolls
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        This scrolls
    </a>   

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.scroll{
    width:100%;
    height:398px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.scroll a{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    background:#369;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: I have modified your jsfiddle by adding another div block inside the "a" block. The out put can be found here.. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=l0skHCIvK4 whay is the output making some of the blocks slide down?

Comment: @Sai- ah, adding vertical-align:top; to the .scroll a definition will fix it!

Comment: Thanks was able to modify just a little of your solution to get what I needed . Also thanks to the user "Intelligent iguana" for helping me in my jsfiddle.

Comment: I wish I could give you a +1 on the vote/score. But i cant do it coz of my score :( . But thanks a lot

Comment: @Sai Glad to help! Good luck with the project :)